# Function-pointer when returning values

Tags: c++

I am using C language to upgrade my coding skills.

I designed a simple program because I wanted to easily find the problems what I looked for and arrange the works when I handle many problems as shown in below.

Here is my header file

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PROBLEM_H
#define PROBLEM_H

namespace PROBLEM_1 { int do_main(); }

typedef int(*MAINFUNC)();

#endif
```

And below is my source file.

```
#include "problems.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef int(*MAINFUNC)(void);

map<string, MAINFUNC> func_map;

void initialize_problem_map(void) {
    func_map["problem_1"] = PROBLEM_1::do_main;
}

namespace PROBLEM_1 {
    int do_main(void) {
        cout << "hi" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    string problem;

    initialize_problem_map();
    cin >> problem;

    if (func_map.find(problem) != func_map.end())
        return (*(func_map[problem]))();


    return -1;  
}
```

If I input "PROBLEM_1" then, the do_main functions in namespace PROBLEM_1 will be executed. I think that this design helps me organize multiple coding problems.

However, my question is about these two code lines as below.

```
if (func_map.find(problem) != func_map.end())
    return (*(func_map[problem]))();
```

As you can see, the main fucntion's return type is "int". However, in the if-clause, i think that it return function-pointer. Therefore, I thought that those returning behavior is mismatched with the main function's return type. But, to my surprise, it worked well.

Could u explain this procedures regarding returning types?

Comment: You write "I am using C language", but as your tag and code show, you are using C++.

Comment: off topic: `func_map.find` returns an iterator to the found item or `end()`. You know that, obviously, but you can also use that iterator to eliminate the need to perform the exact same look-up for `func_map[problem]`. Eg: `map<string, MAINFUNC>::iterator it = func_map.find(problem); if (it != func_map.end()) return (*(it->second))();` See also [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) for a different take on the find and see also  [C++11's std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to eliminate the need for function pointers.

Comment: If you are using C++ (and I assume you are as I can see maps, string, iostream etc) then you should use cstdio instead of stdio.h. Although I don't really know why do you need it :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func_map[problem]`, indeed, results in a function pointer. Applying the operator `()` on it, the function is invoked and the expression results in an `int`. Dereferencing a function pointer before its invocation is optional. This is symmetric with an optional address taking on a function name for initializing function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed

```
 func_map[problem]
```

is a pointer. However, you dereference the pointer with *:

```
 *(func_map[problem])
```

and call function by adding ():

```
 (*(func_map[problem]))()
```

which returns "int".

Answer (score 0):

find returns an iterator; if this iterator is end, then the problem does not exist in the map; Because it is not end, it exists, then in the return line the pointer function obtained with [] is used to call it.